# How can I get the dir of a php script that's running in CLI?

Tags: php, command-line-interface

I have a CLI PHP script and I need to know what directory it's currently running in. Because of some operations, including `getcwd()`, the directory has changed a bit.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `__DIR__` [predefined constant](http://php.net/manual/language.constants.predefined.php).

Comment: He's accepted the answer, so I assume this is what he wants. But this gets the directory of where the original PHP file actually sits, after resolving symlinks. It is not the directory where it's "currently running in."

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you want: dirname(__FILE__)

http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php